# Giving a python function the same signature as another function

Tags: python, pycharm

Suppose I have a function

```
def my_original_func(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5):
    print(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
```

I want to create another function that does exactly the same as this function, but want it laid out as follows:

```
@a_decorator(my_original_func)
def my_new_func(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Where I am envisioning a_decorator looking something like:

```
def a_decorator(func):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func_sig = inspect.signature(func)

        def my_copy_func(*args, **kwargs):
           return func(*args, **kwargs)

        my_copy_func.__signature__ = func_sig

        return my_copy_func

    return wrapper
```

Motivation: my_new_func is intended to be client code, whereas my_original_func isn't (my_new_func will actually wrap my_original_func in another function, rather than return the same thing). I would rather not explicitly state the inputs, and then there are multiple functions in the code with that signature that need to be updated when the signature changes which I would rather avoid.

In particular, I want my IDE (PyCharm currently) to be able to recognise that my_new_func accepts the same arguments as my_original_func, and suggest these to me when I'm using the function (rather than *args and **kwargs).

Comment: PyCharm's *static* analysis will not be able to understand your *dynamically* defined signature.

Comment: Ah. In a jupyter notebook, what I gave above seems to work. I assume that jupyter notebooks work differently to PyCharm in this context then? So is there no way I can tell pycharms static analysis that it should have the same signature as my_original_func?

Comment: It will work if you run the cell with your `my_new_func` because it's already set the new signature. If you just write it without running, pretty sure jupyter will not be able to understand that prior to executing the cell.

Comment: Only by writing it with the same signature. Maybe you should rethink your structure, so you don't need to change the signature in multiple places.